# How to get post ID of Facebook shared URL, or how to get all posts shared via Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

## Goal

My goal is for a user to share something he created on my site to Facebook, and for me to display all comments on my own page using the Facebook comments plugin.

So my ideal flow would be:

1. User creates content with example id `vjrjf834fdkfj`, and shares using public URL `http://example.com/vjrjf834fdkfj/`.
2. User shares this URL on Facebook via my Facebook app ID. The post ID is 1234567.
3. I get this post ID. ***(This is what I need help with)***
4. I store this in my database.
5. Whenever a visitor visit the page `http://example.com/vjrjf834fdkfj/` I look up in the database what the post ID is (1234567 in this example), and call the Facebook comments plugin using this post ID.

## What I tried

### Attempt #1

First failed attempt: read the `post_id` field of the `FB.ui` callback but this response is typically empty because [Facebook says that](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#advancedtopics):

> Only available if the user is logged into your app using Facebook and
>   has granted publish_actions. If present, this is the ID of the
>   published Open Graph story.

My user is not always logged into my app via Facebook, because he can also create a normal account.

### Attempt #2

So my next attempt was to get a list of all posts of this app by calling the Graph API. I have a "basic" app with the "Website" platform set to my website URL (`www.example.com`). Given this list I might filter this on the relevant URL and voila, get the post ID for the right URL.

I can create an access token and call `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{app-id}/objects?access_token={token}`, but this gives an error `The parameter type is required`. And when I try to get a list of object types by calling the `/object_types` endpoint, I get an empty list.

### Attempt #3

I also played a bit with creating a Page Tab but the documentation makes no sense to me as to how that would apply to my case. I ended up with two extra pages, all empty, and not what I want. However, I could live with an extra page on my Facebook page showing a list of all posts that have been shared (so these posts would appear here and on my user's timeline).

## Questions

So:

- Why is this `object_types` list empty? I expect that something like "post" would show up here, allowing me to get a list of all posts associated with this app ID.
- If this is not possible, how can I still achieve my end goal?

Thanks.

Comment: _"Why is this object_types list empty?"_ - because it shows the Open Graph objects you have defined in your app settings, and has nothing to do with normal shares.

Comment: If the user doesn't grant you user_posts or publish_actions you will not be able to get it

Comment: @WizKid So even though people share via MY app and people are sharing from MY page, I cannot get the post ID if people have not logged in with Facebook or have not given me the publish_actions/user_posts permission?